# Random generator using arc4random in jailbreak app

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, arc4random

i'm developing an app with Theos and i want to add a random image generator. 
i have an nsarray of image and i don't know how to use arc4random (). 
can you help me showing some sample code? (:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435905/arc4random-random-number-generator to actually get the random value. Is that what you're interested in - is there anything else?

Answer (score 2):

```
int k = arc4random_uniform(myArray.count);

UIImageView *picToShow = [myArray objectAtIndex:k]; // show image
```

Comment: i use your method but the mobile terminal said that i have to declare arc4random_uniform xD

Comment: try including stdlib with: #include <stdlib.h>